# How to add checkbox into manufacturers in Magento?

Tags: module, magento-1.9

I've changed the way how brands are displayed in menu (logos/images instead of a just text/names).
But there is a problem I can't solve. How to add a field (show/hide) into the manufacturers(Brands) table ? Or which table contain all the manufacturers (can't locate it) .
In the meantime I was testing some solutions but ... it does not work ;(

Tried to add field into eav_attributes, then based on value 0/1 show or hide brand in the list of favourites :)

Any ideas ?

Here is how or what i would like to achieve:
"checkbox" not a "radio". My module will let me display a favourite brands inside dropdown menu in order: favourite brands/products first then all non favourite (limited to 10 in dropdown then "see more" ... if required :)).
Checkbox will be used to select these brands (if checked will be shown as a "Favourite brand/product").
(images presents products but checkbox will work with brands in menu "Brands" - for now)
[My menu - example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fz7F.png)
[My menu - example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL1wS.png)
currently displays only some products but none of those products is "in promotion/featured" because I can't select them yet.

So that's the plan ;)

Answer (score 0):

do you need checkbox? or radio box like you showed on screen?

both of them needs a lot of work,

1* 
if you need radio button you should duplicate 'default_value' logic,

- in database: eav_attribute you should add custom_field column.
- then in: Mage_Eav_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute_Edit_Options_Abstract add logic similar to defaultValue
- and add logic to the eav/attribute/options.phtml

2*
for checkbox, you should add column in database:

- eav_attribute_option and modify same class and template.
- then modify same class and template as you need

as modify I mean copy to local codepool and then add your logic.

may I ask why you need that? I am not sure if this sollution is the best for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post any answer or reedit my post - weird is this forum :)